# d3 mouseout not fired in nested group

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I've built a graph in D3 where nodes can have multiple colors (e.g. `120°` of the node is blue, another `120°` slice is green and the remaining `120°` yellow).
So the node is basically no longer a `SVG circle` element anymore but a `pie chart` that is based on `path` elements.

For interactivity reasons I increase the `pie chart's` radius if the user hovers over it. In order to scale it back, I'd like to listen to the `mouseout` event. My problem is that my event listener does not fire on `mouseout`. However it does fire on `mouseover`:

```
let node = this.nodeLayer.selectAll('.node')
     .data(data, (n) => n.id);
node.exit().remove();

let nodeEnter = node.enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('id', (n) => `calls function that generates a unique ID`)
  .on('mouseover', this.nodeMouseOverHandler)
  .on('mouseout', this.nodeMouseOutHandler)
```

If I only want to display, one color, I render a `circle`. If I want to display more than 1 color, I render a `pie chart`

```
nodeEnter.merge(node).each((d, i, nodes) => {
   // call a function that returns a radius depending on whether the mouse pointer is currently hovering over the node
   const radius = ...


   // if I want to render one color
   nodeEnter.append('circle')
      //... customize

   // if I want to render multiple colors
   const arc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(0)
      .outerRadius(radius);

   const pie = d3.pie()
     .value((d) => 1)
     .sort(null);

   // dummy colors
   const colors = ['#ff0000', '#00ff00];
   enter.append('g')
     .selectAll('path')
     .data(pie(colors))
     .enter()
     .append('path')
     .attr('shape-rendering', 'auto')
     .attr('d', arc)
     .attr('fill', (d, i) => {
       return colors[i];
     })
     .on('mouseout', (d, i, elems) => {
        console.log('mouseout in subgroup');
        this.nodeMouseOutHandler(d, elems[i]);
     });
});
```

For the `pie chart`, the `nodeMouseOverHandler` fires perfectly fine, however the `nodeMouseOutHandler` doesn't fire at all. If I render a circle instead of the pie chart, everything works perfectly fine. Any ideas why I cannot observe the `mouseout` event?

Comment: You are not passing the DOM element (`this`)  to your function.

Comment: Sry. forgot it whilte posting the question. The thing is that not even the log statement "mouseout in subgroup" is printed if the pie chart is rendered

Comment: In that case the problem is more complex. Any chance of a [MCVE]? By the way, `this` is `elems[i]` in those arguments.

Comment: Will be difficult. That thing lives in a huge codebase

Comment: I think this may be a contexto issue, what is `this` inside your `mouseout` function?

Comment: The thing is that the callback doesn't fire at all with the pie chart. I would be happy if it would print out "mouseout in subgroup"

Comment: @slashburn Wait a minute, are you setting a `mouseout` listener to the group **and** to the inner paths?

Comment: Yes, at first I didn't have a listener on the path elements, I only had a listener on the parent group element. Because that didn't work, I've also added a listener to the path child elements

Comment: @slashburn Remove the listener to the groups and leave only the listener to the paths, and tell me if you see the console.log.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. But in the meantime, I was able to resolve it. The problem was that in order to increase the nodes radius a rerender was triggered. The rerender removed the node from the graph and readded it again. Therefore mouseover was called again and so on. This led to an endless loop. As soon as I prevented the flood of events, it worked. But thank you very much for your efforts Gerardo. Really appreciate your help!